# Как добавлять данные в DataFrame в пределах одной или двух функций?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Задача: Есть TKinter приложение, при нажатии на кнопку - вызывается диалоговое окно, выбираем файл excel. Путь файла попадает в функцию для обработки Pandas этого файла. Файл обрабатывается, результат пишется в другой excel файл на диск. Функция отрабатывает без return. И насколько я понимаю DataFrame обнуляется. Мне нужно чтобы нажимая на одну и туже кнопку в DataFrame можно было грузить данные из разных файлов.

Проблема: в пределах одной функции не могу сделать:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_excel_path, header=0, usecols="D,C,A", encoding='utf8')
df.columns=['Title-D', 'Title-C', 'Title-A']
df_temp = pd.DataFrame()
df_finish = pd.concat([df, df_temp], sort=False)
```

Потому что затирается DataFrame при вызове нового файла

Как вывести результат DataFrame в переменную из функции?
Пробовал через return, но не возвращает.
Короче говоря мне надо как то хранить результат внутри функции.
Какие есть способы хранить DataFrame для присоединения к другим DataFrame?

Запасной вариант это брать данных из файла что пишется на диск, но этот файл перезаписывается полностью, не хотелось бы грузить файловую систему, как это в памяти делать не понимаю.

UPD 1

Получилось сделать так, в теле одной функции работает добавление в DataFrame всех следующих файлов открываемых при нажатии кнопки. Однако только если совпадает название и количество колонок. Что то мне подсказывает что придется использовать не жесткую привязку к колонкам, а mapping как предлагал уважаемый MaxU. Вот теперь думаю получится ли, объединить решение через mapping и функцию загрузки файлов через кнопку.

```
dfs = []
def load_local_file_excel():
    file_excel_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=path.dirname(__file__),
                                             filetypes=(("Excel 97", "*.xls"),
                                                        ("Excel 2007", "*.xlsx"),
                                                        ("all files", "*.*")))

df = pd.read_excel(file_excel_path,
                   header=0,
                   usecols="D,C,A",
                   encoding='utf8',columns = ['in_stock', 'price_max', 'artikul_new'])


dfs.append(df)
cols = ['artikul_new', 'price_max', 'in_stock']
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0, ignore_index=True, sort=False)[cols]

df.to_excel('output_local.xlsx', index=False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос вы хотите объединить данные из разных файлов в едином DataFrame добавляя по одному файлу.

Пример:

```
def add_data(df, filename, **kwargs):
    tmp = pd.read_excel(filename, **kwargs)
    return df.append(tmp, sort=False)

names = ['Phone','Name','City']
df = pd.DataFrame()
df = df.pipe(add_data, r'C:\temp\f1.xlsx', skiprows=1, 
             header=None, names=names, usecols='C, B, A')
df = df.pipe(add_data, r'C:\temp\f2.xlsx', skiprows=1, 
             header=None, usecols='A, C, B, D',
             names=names+['Email'])
```

PS вас ждёт неприятный сюрприз - при использовании параметра `usecols="D,C,A"` - `pd.read_excel()` выберет только указанные столбцы, но в оригинальном порядке: `"A,C,D"`